# Why is jquery show() not working in example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please consider this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/EqdPdjsnrhob3mTqeJAP?p=preview). It's purpose is to provide a very simple simulation of a loading mechanism.

I have a simple set up:

```
  <body>
    <div id="loading">
      <img src="http://www.arabianbusiness.com/skins/ab.main/gfx/loading_spinner.gif"/>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <h3>Content fully loaded.</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Where `content` is hidden through CSS:

```
body 
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The Javascript is equally simple:

```
$(window).ready(function() 
{
  simulateLongLoad();
  $('#content').show();
});

function simulateLongLoad() 
{
  setTimeout(showContent, 2000);
}

function showContent() 
{
  $('#loading').hide();
  $('#content').show();
}
```

But, for some reason the `.show()` of #content doesn't work. Any idea why?

*PS: Likely something very stupid, but I don't see it.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in css write `display:none;` and not visibility

Read More about the difference over [**Here**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

**For Explanation :**

> display:none means that the tag in question will not appear on the
> page at all (although you can still interact with it through the dom).
> There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags.
>
> visibility:hidden means that unlike display:none, the tag is not
> visible, but space is allocated for it on the page. The tag is
> rendered, it just isn't seen on the page.

But if you want to use visibility , and want to show/hide using JQuery,then use below

```
$('#element').css('visibility', 'visible'); //to show
$('#element').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //to hide
```

Comment: @ParthTrivedi : i am just telling him to correct his css

Comment: Yep, had to be something simple like that. Strange that it doesn't work on visibility though.

Comment: @Spikee :I have given the explanation , which you can go through

Comment: @Spikee if you want to use visibility use this `$('#content').css('visibility', 'visible');`

Comment: @Spikee : and as i answered first ,, i won't mind if you mark it as an answer :P

Answer (score 5):

You need to change `visibility:hidden` to `display:none` and remove your second line of JS (you run the same code 2 times).

```
 $('#content').show();
```

this code adds css to `#content` elemment `display:block` not `visibility:visible`.
If you want to use `visibility:hidden` style you must change your code to be

```
$('#content').css('visibility','visible');
```

Answer (score 3):

your content `visibility: hidden` should be `display: none` and your second line of JS in the onload was not needed, see here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MHbBjuCEVrIGpKarooLF

Comment: Yep, that extra line was a leftover from a test, I removed it as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to jQuery, [(...)This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block")](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

So, this function wont change the css property 'visibility'